# Has anything in Quantum Physics been verified experimentally?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I want to  know if anything In Quantum Physics has been verified experimentally because I think it is just theoretically proven.

Comment: Check out 18 different [experiments](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_quantum_mechanics) written only on Wikipedia and there are thousands of more experiments performed since the very early days of its formulation.

Comment: So its proven experimentally?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its based on a wrong assumption.

Comment: I am not able to delete this question

Comment: close this question

Comment: @Dingus45191 I think it is useful as a question - it is always good to remind that science is not something to *believe* in or not believe - it is based on hard experimental evidence.

Comment: Ok thanks Physicists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such thing as theoretical proof.  The predictions of quantum mechanics have been *experimentally* validated over and over and over for the past hundred years.  My [*entire job*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope) is fundamentally based on the phenomenon of [quantum tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling).  If you want experimental evidence that electrons behave like waves, here is an image of one trapped in a ring of atoms called a quantum corral, produced with an instrument like the one I am using at this very moment.

[image]

Flash drives store information by allowing electrons to quantum tunnel through barriers. Transistors are built based on the principle of quantum mechanics applied to materials called semiconductors. The fact that visible light passes through glass while UV light does not is a [prediction of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_and_translucency#UV-Vis:_Electronic_transitions) which cannot be understood classically.  The fact that solids are rigid and stable is a result which is [explained quantum mechanically](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-27056-6_37), not classically.  The **entire field** of chemistry, including the idea of chemical bonds and the periodic table and the existence of atoms themselves, is predicted beautifully by quantum mechanics while being radically different from the [catastrophic prediction](https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=15650) of classical models.

I could go on and on and on.  Quantum mechanics is experimentally verified many thousands of times - probably more - every day.

Answer (score 5):

*Theory* is by definition a *hypothesis* confirmed experimentally. Quantum physics has been an established field of science with a hundred years of experimental and theoretical research. It is quantum physics that is behind all modern electronics, cell phones, laser shows etc.

If we take less *everyday* phenomena - such as those related to elementary particles - they have been studied experimentally in well publicized experiments on particle colliders.

It is necessary to point out that we are well beyond *proving* quantum theory (quantum mechanics and quantum electrodynamics) theoretically and experimentally - by now it is merely an element of other branches, such as condensed matter theory, quantum optics, etc. Just like mechanics is a building block for hydrodynamics, elasticity theory, etc. If I were to criticize quantum theory and its offshoots, I'd rather say that it has become too much of an engineering than science.

Comment: What ? Proving in Theory and proving by experiment is different

Comment: *thery* and *proving in theory* are not the same thing. Quantum physics is behind the solid state theory, that is the basis of modern electronics - if your comupter or cell-phone works, count it as an experimental confirmation.

Comment: Ok understood it

Comment: @Dingus45191 Physics theories have to be correct mathematically, in that sense "proven" but there can be millions of what people may call "physics theory" that are really science fiction. Physics theories have to be **validated** continually, i.e. fit data and predict future data. If the prediction is wrong, than the physics theory is reexamined and new   additions are made, or a new theory in order to fit the new data. The standard model of particle  physics at present is not the standard model  of fifty years ago.